# Adding a WCF service inside a Website for publishing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I have a website hosted on IIS and users can access it externally on the internet. Now I want to use the same domain name to my webservice as well and allow users to access it on the internet, so I just added the published code folder for the service inside my website so the URl will be something like below.

Website : http://mytestsite.com/home

WCF Service : http://mytestsite.com/services/testservice.svc

but when I try to use testservice.svc I am getting an error saying

> The service '/mytestsite/services/testservice.svc' cannot
>   be activated due to an exception during compilation. The exception
>   message is: The type 'AWL.AI.WWIP.SBLPayService', provided as
>   the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided
>   in the configuration element
>   system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could
>   not be found..

AWL.AI.WWIP is the namespace of the service and the contract. The service is a separate solution in itself with the name AWL.AI.WWIP. Now I tried to add that folder inside my website and it throws this error. Even if I rename the folder to match the namespace name it does not work. It throws the same error. Any help will be very much apprecited.

Comment: For a service to run on a web server it needs 3 things, 1) a contract, 2) an implementation, and 3) a ServiceHost.  You can configure an endpoint all via web.config or you can use the built-in .svc file type to create your ServiceHost.  Just go double check all your settings and read the exception message!  Your error message says it can't find the type specified by your .svc page or by your web.config

Comment: Was there any reason you had an `MVC` site and opted for `WCF` instead of `WebAPI`? It would have been less of a headache because you now have 2 distinct applications that can (as you can see) be challenging to _configure_ properly (parent app vs child app configs, etc.). WCF _itself_ is a pain to configure...

Comment: Unsure if you can do this based on your hosting: see if a _virtual directory_ (meaning it can be anywhere in the web server file system, not necessarily as a child folder of your web app), set to be _its own application domain_, will at least help in "de coupling" your 2 distinct applications

Comment: why not refactor your project since we could add service.svc(service host) to web application directly. https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXoQ3.png  Beside, do not break IIS virtual path folder structure, which will prevent IIS from properly hosting these services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for all the inputs, I was able to find the solution. I added the services folder within my website folder as I mentioned in my question. And converted the services folder to an application. In IIS you have this option, right click the folder and you have the option to convert to Application. I did that and it created a node under my website name and there you go, you can access the services without any changes and using the website domain.
So I can now say,

> http://mytestsite.com/services/testservice.svc

in the browser and bingo! you see the service. No changes to web.config required.